Intersection of restricted cubic spline with log relative hazard = 0
I would like to determine the intersection of a restricted cubic spline with log relative hazard = 0 (i.e. the change from a lower hazard to a higher hazard). Thank you!
fit <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(age, 4), data = df, x = TRUE, y = TRUE, surv = TRUE)
ggplot(Predict(fit))

